# Delegates the Calculation of a Property of a Superclass to its Subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

In the book, Python in a Nutshell,

the authors claim the following code snippet is problematic:

```py
class B:
    def f(self):
        return 23
    g = property(f)
class C(B):
    def f(self):
        return 42

c = C()
print(c.g)                # prints: 23, not 42
```

And the solution, as the authors claimed, is to redirect the calculation of property `c.g` to the class `C`'s implementation of `f` at the superclass `B`'s level.

```py
class B:
    def f(self):
        return 23
    def _f_getter(self):
        return self.f()
    g = property(_f_getter)
class C(B):
    def f(self):
        return 42

c = C()
print(c.g)                # prints: 42, as expected
```

I disagree but please help me to understand why the authors claimed as they did.

Two reasons for my disagreement.

1. Superclasses are far likely to be in upstream modules and it is not ideal for upstream modules to implement additional indirection to take into account that subclasses in downstream modules may reimplement the getter method for the superclass property.
2. The calculation of a property of a superclass is done after the instantiation of an instance of the superclass. An instance of the subclass must be instantiated after the instantiation of an instance of the superclass. Therefore, if the writer of C does not explicitly "declare" `C.g` to be a property with a different implementation `C.f`, then it should rightly inherits the property `B.g` and i.e. `c.g` should be `b.g`.

My question is:

am I right with this thought or are the authors right with their claims?

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight more in depth explanation of what is happening.

Basically in your first snippet (which is not very idiomatic python), you bind the exising `B.f` method to `B.g`, when `C` inherits `g`, its still bound to `B.f`. `g` is basically statically linked to `B.f`.

```py
class B:
    def f(self):
        return 23

    g = property(f)  # B.f gets bound to B.g as property


class C(B):
    def f(self):
        return 42

    # C.g not redeclared is still bound to B.f
```

The "correction snippet" is even less idiomatic, and bind a method which will retrieve the `f` method from `self`, the instance it is run on, which makes it dynamic because if `self`'s `f` method is different from `B.f`, then the result changes. However we still bind statically to a private method.

```py
class B:
    def f(self):
        return 23

    def _f_getter(self):
        return self.f()

    g = property(_f_getter)  # B._f_getter gets bound to B.g, but B._f_getter uses the f method of self

class C(B):

    def f(self):
        return 42

    # C.g is still bound to B._f_getter but the f method of self has changed
```

This is the idiomatic way of using `property`, as a decorator around another method. We can use the same principle as above, but rather than declaring a private intermediate method, we can use `g` as a name directly.

```py
class B:
    def f(self):
        return 23

    @property
    def g(self):  # no binding the B.g property uses f method of self directly
        return self.f()

class C(B):

    def f(self):
        return 42

    # C.g uses f method of self which has changed
```

Comment: A good explanation!

Comment: Then again, if you're a writer of an upstream module, would you wrap your property around another function that calls the getter? I still think its unidiomatic to defer the call to another method. It is the responsibility of the downstream writer of subclass to wrap property around a function with the same name he intends to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

*"The calculation of a property of a superclass is done after the instantiation of an instance of the superclass. "* - NO, the property is declared along with a class declaration and it's tied to a target function in that class.

```
print(vars(B)['g'])  # <property object at 0x7f5f799ebce0>
```

*"An instance of the subclass must be instantiated after the instantiation of an instance of the superclass."* - NO again. That's obvious. Declaration and instantiation are different processes.

*"Therefore, if the writer of `C` does not explicitly "declare" `C.g` to be a property with a different implementation `C.f`, then it should rightly inherits the property `B.g`"* - It inherits `g` property object in its state on **declaration** phase (i.e. **tied** to `B.f` function).

So, you naturally have valid options:

- to override a *property* in your subclass
- or to declare your initial *property* object to consider inheritance, which is no bad

---

```
class B:
    def f(self):
        return 23
    g = property(lambda self: self.f())

class C(B):
    def f(self):
        return 42

c = C()
print(c.g)  # 42
```

Comment: Yes, but as an example: `def name(self): return self._name` for `class Person: ... self._name = name` and `class Child(Person): ...`; Child instance cannot instantiate without the variable `name` and if writer of Child did not reimplement getter of `name` property, it should defer it to the getter of `name` property of `Person`. As in the writer should declare `name = property(...some def that returns self._name...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `property` but why don't you use:

```
class B:
    def f(self):
        return 23

    @property
    def g(self):
        return self.f()

class C(B):
    def f(self):
        return 42

c = C()
print(c.g)
print(type(c.g))

# Output
42
int
```

It's not the same as your initial code?

Comment: It is different because yours calls the `f` of `self` (which can change) while the first example bound the currently defined `f` (=23) to `g`. Yours is also a much more idiomatic way to implement the second snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification. I learnt something :-)